# Modifying a double list with "move all" button

Tags: java

I am working on a GUI (that this community has been extremely helpful with so far) and I have reached another important step I need to achieve.

Currently my GUI consists of a JOptionsPane. Inside this pane is a panel that contains two lists and four buttons. Two of the buttons are arrows who's text is ">" and "<". (The buttons are in between both lists.)

Those buttons work correctly. A user can select one of the objects from the first list and then click the > and it will move to the second list and visa versa.

Next I need to add a feature where there is a ">>" button. This will move all the items in the first list to the second. I really have no idea how to handle this part. I am assuming it is some type of while loop although I'm not entirely sure.

First allow me to post the simple snipplet that shows the > button.

```
buttonin = new JButton("        >         ");
        buttonin.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                int[] fromindex = outputDetails.getSelectedIndices();
                Object[] from = outputDetails.getSelectedValues();

                for(int i=0; i< from.length; i++){
                    output.addElement(from[i]);
                    System.out.println(output);
                }

                for(int i = (fromindex.length-1); i>=0; i--){
                    input.remove(fromindex[i]);
                }
            }
        });
```

Next I will post the full code in case that is needed to understand what I am trying to achieve. I hope this is enough information for someone to assist me if not I apologize, the actual program is very long and I couldn't think of an easy way to isolate this test case.

```
public static void displayGUI(){

        int result = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, getPanel(),"JOptionPane Example : ", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null, new String[]{"Confirm","Create Return"}, "default");

        if(result == 1){
            initialScreenDecisions="NONE";
            MainWriter.finishedCounter=true;
            System.out.println(MainWriter.finishedCounter);
            while(MainWriter.entryDetails.size()>0){
                MainWriter.entryDetails.remove(0);
            }
            while(output.size()>0){
                output.remove(0);
            }
        }
    }


    private static JPanel getPanel(){

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JPanel panelTop = new JPanel();
        JPanel topButtons = new JPanel();
        JPanel bottomButtons = new JPanel();


        String text = "<html>"
                +"Batch <font size=6 color=>"+MainWriter.batchHeaderCounter+"</font> of <font size=6>"+BatchCounter.BatchTotal+"</font>"
                +"<br>Batch Header:  <font size=5><font color=red>"+MainWriter.BatchHeader+"</font>"
                +"</html>";
        JLabel topLabel = new JLabel(text);



        panelTop.add(topLabel);

        input = new DefaultListModel();
        output = new DefaultListModel();

        String[] shoppingItems = new String[MainWriter.entryDetails.size()];
        shoppingItems = MainWriter.entryDetails.toArray(shoppingItems);

        for(int i = 0; i < shoppingItems.length; i++){
            input.addElement(shoppingItems[i]);
        }

        outputDetails = new JList(input);
        outputDetails.setVisibleRowCount(10);
        outputDetails.setFixedCellHeight(20);
        outputDetails.setFixedCellWidth(400);
        outputDetails.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);

        JScrollPane list1 = new JScrollPane(outputDetails);

        inputDetails = new JList(output);
        inputDetails.setVisibleRowCount(10);
        inputDetails.setFixedCellHeight(20);
        inputDetails.setFixedCellWidth(400);
        inputDetails.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);

        JScrollPane list2 = new JScrollPane(inputDetails);

        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();

        buttonin = new JButton("        >         ");
        buttonin.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                int[] fromindex = outputDetails.getSelectedIndices();
                Object[] from = outputDetails.getSelectedValues();

                for(int i=0; i< from.length; i++){
                    output.addElement(from[i]);
                    System.out.println(output);
                }

                for(int i = (fromindex.length-1); i>=0; i--){
                    input.remove(fromindex[i]);
                }
            }
        });
        buttonPanel.add(buttonin);

        buttonout = new JButton("        <         ");
        buttonout.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                Object[] to = inputDetails.getSelectedValues();
                int[] toindex = inputDetails.getSelectedIndices();

                for(int i = 0; i < to.length; i++){
                    input.addElement(to[i]);
                }

                for(int i = (toindex.length-1); i >=0; i--){
                    output.remove(toindex[i]);
                }
            }
        });


        buttonall = new JButton("        >>        ");
        buttonall.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

                if(initialScreenDecisions.equals("DEFAULT")){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have selected to add all entry details. Please " +
                                                      "\nclick okay on the next scren to confirm or click " +
                                                      "\n'>>' again to cancel the apply all option.");
                    initialScreenDecisions="ADDALL";
                }else if(initialScreenDecisions.equals("ADDALL")){
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have canceled the apply all option.");
                    initialScreenDecisions="DEFAULT";
                }else{
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You must disable the '<<' option before you can use this.");
                }

            }
        });

        buttonnone = new JButton("        <<        ");
        buttonnone.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                if(initialScreenDecisions.equals("DEFAULT")){

                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have selected to skip the current batch and" +
                                                    "\nomit all of it's entries. Click okay on the next" +
                                                    "\nscreen to confirm or click '<<' again to" +
                                                    "\ncancel the option.");
                initialScreenDecisions="NONE";

                }else if(initialScreenDecisions.equals("NONE")){

                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have canceled the omit all option.");
                    initialScreenDecisions="DEFAULT";

                }else{
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You must disable the '>>' option before you can use this.");
                }



            }
        });

        buttonhelp = new JButton("HELP");
        buttonhelp.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "This screen allows you to determine the entry details from" +
                                                    "\nthe current batch that will be included in the final return." +
                                                    "\nSelect the details you wish to include and click the > arrow to" +
                                                    "\nmove them to the right side. Pressing the >> button will" +
                                                    "\ninclude all entry details for the current batch in the final" +
                                                    "\nreturn. Clicking the < button will move a detail back."+
                                                    "\nClick << to omit the entire batch. Use confirm to continue"+
                                                    "\nto the next step or 'create return' to finish the Nacha return"+
                                                    "\nwith all past additions.");                          
            }
        });         

        buttonPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        topButtons.add(buttonin);
        topButtons.add(buttonall);
        topButtons.add(buttonnone);
        topButtons.add(buttonout);
        bottomButtons.add(buttonhelp);
        buttonPanel.add(topButtons,BorderLayout.NORTH);
        buttonPanel.add(buttonhelp,BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel();
        bottomPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(bottomPanel, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));

        bottomPanel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(10,0)));
        bottomPanel.add(list1);
        bottomPanel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(5,0)));
        bottomPanel.add(buttonPanel);
        bottomPanel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(5,0)));
        bottomPanel.add(list2);
        bottomPanel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(10,0)));

        panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        panel.add(panelTop,BorderLayout.NORTH);
        panel.add(bottomPanel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        panel.setOpaque(true);



        return panel;
    }
```

You can ignore the above >> button contents. Right now it will allow the user to select all of the items in the list it just doesn't visually show the selection. If I get the >> button to move all the items at once then I won't need the extra steps you can see I have implemented.

Comment: What is the purpose of declaring `String[] shoppingItems` and using `shoppingItems[i]`? Could you not use `input.addElement(MainWriter.entryDetails.get(i));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not too sure what all your variable types are, but I think this should work in your ActionListener for `>>`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < input.getSize(); i++) {
    output.addElement(input.get(i));
}
input.clear();
```

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thanks very much for the help and I can clearly see what you did so now I understand.